# How to use EF Include method(to load related data) in F#?

Tags: entity-framework, f#, eager-loading, c#-to-f#

How to eager load related data in F# using Include method I tried this one: 
`_ctx.Reports.Include(x => x.Category)`
and getting the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   FS0041  A unique overload for method 'Include' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed.
>
> Known type of argument:  ^_arg3
>
> Candidates:
>    - (extension) Linq.IQueryable.Include<'TEntity when 'TEntity : not struct>(navigationPropertyPath: string) : Linq.IQueryable<'TEntity>
>    - (extension) Linq.IQueryable.Include<'TEntity,'TProperty when 'TEntity : not struct>(navigationPropertyPath: Linq.Expressions.Expression>) : Query.IIncludableQueryable<'TEntity,'TProperty>    SharpNews.Application   E:\0DevelopingLearn\BackEnd\ASP.NET Core\SharpNews\SharpNews.Application\Admin\Report\GetReports.fs 44  Active

and also two errors are saying x is undefined

Am I using an incorrect syntax?

Comment: Yes, you can use `Include` and even `ThenInclude` just like in C#. What have you tried so far? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting to `seq` or `IEnumerable<_>` will do the trick

```
context.Users
    .Include(fun u -> u.Roles :> seq<Role>)
```

```
open System.Collections.Generic

context.Users
    .Include(fun u -> u.Roles :> IEnumerable<Role>)
        .ThenInclude(fun r -> r.Permissions)
```